# PHP regular expression to replace value surrounded by letters or whitespace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, expression

I have been trying to come up with a solution for some time now but haven't found one that works reliably.

I have a string in which each newline is represented as a zero (0)

```
$string ="The quick brown fox0jumped over the lazy dog 0with 1308mm to spare.";
```

I'm looking for a way to replace each 0 that isn't part of a number with the html tag "br".

So far the closest I got was:

```
preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z ])0([a-zA-Z ])/', '$1\<br\>$2', $string);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something like this, you should use assertions:

```
/(?<!\d)0(?!\d)/
```

Additionally, the second argument is just a string. There is absolutely no need to escape the angle brackets - in fact you wouldn't need to escape them in a regex either. So just use `<br>` as your second argument.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Will need to look into Lookahead and Lookbehind assertions some more.